# Byte[] from Registry returns only one letter

Tags: c#, registry, byte, return, character

I'm trying to read data from the registry @ ""SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs\"

The return value I get is System.byte[], when I convert it to a string like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643213/converting-byte-recieved-from-the-registry-to-string).

It works (I think). But I only get 1 letter returned and not the whole string.

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong? I'm fairly certain there can't be only one letter in there..

I've tried `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);` and `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);` and `Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);` but it all returns only 1 character/letter.

I've checkout this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483087/c-get-registry-key-returns-only-one-char) as well. But thats for C++ and I'm using C# and don't see that Method that they suggested (RegGetValueA)

Here is my code:

```
        RegistryKey pRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser;
        pRegKey = pRegKey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\RecentDocs\\");
        Object val = pRegKey..GetValue("0");

        byte[] bytes = (byte[])pRegKey.GetValue ("0");
        string str = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);

        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("The value is: " + str);
```

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string is encoded using UTF-16, so you should use [`Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx).

But it doesn't seem it's *just* UTF-16 encoded strings, there's some more data. For me, (when decoded as UTF-16), it displays as

```
Stažené soubory□Š6□□□□□Stažené soubory.lnk□T□□뻯□□□□*□□□□□□□□□□□□Stažené soubory.lnk□6□
```

Stažené soubory means Downloads in Czech, which is the language of my Windows. And the U+25A1 squares in the above text are actually zero chars.

Comment: I have almost no knowledge of encoding. :( What "other data" is there and can I access it as well? Sorry if my question is dumb :)

Comment: Why some places UTF-16 is used and some UTF-8 ,I mean what is purpose of that?

Comment: @Lagrangian, the native encoding of (modern) Windows is UTF-16. I don't know of any place in Windows that uses UTF-8.

Comment: @tone7, no idea. Try searching for that or ask another question.

Comment: I'll try searching it =) Thank you for your time and help. It is much appreciated! Have a nice day! :)

Comment: Great @svick one more thing may be a really dumb question what is native encoding

Comment: @Lagrangian, the encoding that Windows uses internally and the one that most (all?) of the API accepts. There are ANSI versions of many API functions too, but they are just for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that the encoding is ASCII ?

I would suspect some UTF like `Encoding.UTF8` or `Encoding.Unicode` - try that...

Comment: Hi thanks for your swift reply :D I tried Encoding.Unicode and it worked!! Thanks a lot. Although I'm sure I did try it. I'm very new to C# and have little knowledge of encoding. Thanks a lot though :)